# UITableView reorder hides background

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that implements the reorder controls. It all works great with the exception of one thing. When I drag the cell, all `UIView` subviews are hidden. Is there a way to prevent that from happening? I tried to add a `UIImage` for the background (semi-transparent) to appear when you enter edit mode, but that caused another issue where the image was resized to the left side of the handles.

Comment: How did you add the hiding subviews to the cell? As subviews of the cell's `view` or the cell's `contentView`? For a custom background while editing, you should subclass `UITableViewCell` and override `-setEditing:`.

Comment: The hiding of the subviews happens automagically. I am using a subclassed UITableviewcell, I tried setEditing, but I have no idea what to do in there to prevent this. If there was a delegate method for when you are dragging a cell in editing mode, that would be helpful

Comment: I have this same issue — UITableViewCell appears to hide or somehow make transparent the `contentView` when the cell is being dragged in a re-order operation. I have found it necessary to add an extra dummy subview to `contentView`, and then add all actual content views to that.

Comment: I think you should add some images to better reflect the problem you're having, and eventually any sample code that you feel may be relevant.

Comment: rather than add to the contentView have you tried adding your background to the cell's backgroundView ?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `backgroundView` of `UITableViewCell` and add the subviews to the `backgroundView`: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/backgroundView

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can create your custom tableview with your own requirements.
You can also use collection view as table view and enable rearrange.
If you dont want to do like this you can use this great readymade RTGridView.

https://github.com/rickytan/RTGridView

Let i know if you need any more help on this.