# UITableViewCell reorder clears subview's background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

This question has been asked few times but there don't seem to be any solution to this.

[UITableView reorder hides background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451937/uitableview-reorder-hides-background)

[Subviews of UITableViewCell are not visible while reordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076939/subviews-of-uitableviewcell-are-not-visible-while-reordering)

[Reordering causing subview 's backround color to clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035915/reordering-causing-subview-s-backround-color-to-clear)

I have a custom tableview cell with UILabel in it. When tableview is in edit mode and I drag the cell to reorder, UILabel's background becomes clear color.  I've also found that, if I try to reorder selected cell (my tableview is allowed multiple selection during edit mode), the subview's background color stays.

I tried below methods in my CustomCell but none of them overrides the subview's background color when cell is being dragged.

I want the subview's background color to stay. Is there any method that I missed? Or Apple designed it this way?

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    if (selected) {
        if (self.isEditing) {
            self.customLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }
        else {
            self.customLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }
    }
    else {
            self.customLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];

    if (highlighted) {
        if (self.isEditing) {
            self.customLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }
        else {
            self.customLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }
    }
    else {
        self.customLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing) {
        self.customLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    else {
        self.customLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create your custom UILabel. And overload -drawRect.

```
@interface VALAbel:UILabel
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *bac_color;
@end


@implementation VALabel

-(void)setBac_color:(UIColor *)bac_color
{
_bac_color = bac_color;
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
   [self.bac_color set];

   CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), true);
   CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.bounds);

    [super drawRect:rect];
 }
@end
```

This will help you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I tried your answer and right now background stays but it changes the background color to black. How can I change this color??

Comment: You should set color when creating your label in cell.  self.customLabel.bac_color = [UIColor blueColor]

Comment: Thanks! Please give me some time. It needs some tidying up so I'll get back to you when it's done. Looks like it's going to work :)

Comment: Thanks it's working but just one more issue... It wasn't displaying the text so I added `[super drawRect:rect];` in the `drawRect:`. Now it's displaying but the text color is kind of light gray color and I can't barely see. I'm setting the text color in my CustomCell with `self.customLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];` but it's not working. Any idea what I'm missing??

Comment: Try call super drawRect after setting background color. It is should work great.

Comment: I works ! I appreciate your help! I couldn't find the answer anywhere so I was going to give up, and come up with a different design. Have good day!

Answer (score 5):

Adding a modern solution for Swift 3.

Create a new .swift file and make a custom UIView class:

```
import UIKit

class NeverClearView: UIView {
    override var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            if backgroundColor?.cgColor.alpha == 0 {
                backgroundColor = oldValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Interface Builder, go to the Identity Inspector and set the class to your shiny new NeverClearView class. This will halt it from disappearing during cell reordering.

This solution also works for other UIKit components, for example I had to do the same thing for a UIStepper a second ago.